# This Easy Python code is not working, where am I lacking

Tags: python-3.x

I even assigned the value to `n` at first

```
n=10
def countdown(n):
 if n <= 0:
  print('Blastoff!')
 else:
  print(n)
 countdown(n-1)
```

but when I run it, it shows:

[image: output]

I was expecting to see something like this :

```
3
2
1
Blastoff!
```

Comment: please include the full code, current and expected output

Answer (score 4):

I believe you meant to do the following:

```
n=10
def countdown(n):
   if n <= 0:
      print('Blastoff!')
      return
   else:
      print(n)
      countdown(n-1)

countdown(n)
```

In recursion, you need to have a statement to terminate the recursion, or else it will run without stopping.

When you reach the stopping point (`n <= 0`) you need to return from the function.

Comment: `return` is not actually needed here, as `None` will be implicitly returned. The only issue in OPs code is that `countdown(n - 1)` should be inside the `else` block.

Comment: Tha'ts true, thanks for the comment, even though I think it's more clear with the return statement ^^

Comment: thx, your  code worked but i am just a learner and i am learning through think python by allen doney. Could you just tell me why doesn't he mention the last line' countdown(n) the way you did or was he thinking something else? and it shows nothing If I  don't put the countdown(n) in the end. Why is it like that. what does this countdown(n) really mean?. thx

Comment: Well, Read about python functions. When you type `def` it means that you are declaring on a function. In order to execute the function, you need to call it. the last line actually calls the function and by that, executing the code inside the function. Take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: Yes, thx but i thought we call the function before using it but here it seem like we called it after using it. could you explain thx.

Comment: The function wouldn't get called unless you call her. Without the line `countdown(n)`, the function code would never get execute.